# Select pandas rows, if row element is contained in another row element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like that:

```
real_value, prediction
'invalid', 'inv'
'invalid', 'neg'
'invalid', 'inv'
'negative', 'neg'
'negative', 'neg'
'negative', 'neg'
'positive', 'pos'
'positive', 'pos'
'positive', 'inv'
```

I would like to select all the rows in which the prediction and the real value are a missmatch, in other words **I would like to get a dataframe that looks like**:

```
real_value, prediction
'invalid', 'neg'
'positive', 'inv'
```

I tried `df.loc[~df.prediction.isin(df.real_value)]`, but this doesn't work. It is easy to select based on a SPECIFIC, USER DEFINED value, e.g. `df.loc[~df.prediction.isin(['neg'])]`, but I can't find a way to select based on values occuring within the rows themselves.

How do I get the desired selection? Thanks

Comment: `df.real_value.str[:3].ne(df.prediction)
`

Comment: `df[df.real_value.str[:3].ne(df.prediction)]` This gives you the data frame, it outputs boolean for the above code. A slight modification.

Comment: @WeNYoBen @Danny Thanks! The comments here are based on comparisons (<,>,=,!=), but are there possibilities to use other functions for selection in a data frame? Like the `.isin()` I tried to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following condition:

```
df[df['real_value'].str[:3].ne(df['prediction'])]
```

Output:

```
    real_value  prediction
1   invalid     neg
8   positive    inv
```

`ne` returns Not equal to of series and other. This is element-wise. You cannot use `isin` because that takes an iterable, Series, DataFrame or dict, so you are not comparing the columns `real_value` and `prediction` element-wise.

Comment: Thanks! I see that `.ne(...)` fulfils the functionality of "not equal", but it would be in the spirit of stackoverflow to explain this `.ne(...)` in a few words for other users, please do so. Besides that, this solution is based on a comparison (<,>,=,!=), but are there possibilities to use other functions for selection in a data frame? Like the `.isin()` I tried to use?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

This should help too. [Pandas Flexible Wrappers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)

`df.loc[(df.real_value != df.prediction.astype(str).str[:3])]`

This is probably much neater and based on the comment from @WenYoBen :

```
df[df.Prediction.str[:3].ne(df.real_value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using a mask column which is a bit more flexible if the length of your prediction isn't always the same (which is what the other answers assume):

```
df['mask'] = [x[1] in x[0] for x in zip(df['real_value'], df['prediction'])]
print(df.loc[df['mask'] == False].drop('mask', axis=1))
```

returns:

```
  real_value  prediction
1    invalid         neg  
8   positive         inv
```